# Set range of numbers column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to set a column that can only accept integers ranging from 0 to 10 inclusive in SQL. It is for a rating system.

My current method is `ratingSore int(2,0) not null`

Will this method work, as I will also need to find the average rating using this column

I am afraid that if I try to find the average, it will round to an integer instead of giving me decimals

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL 8.0.16 or higher, you can define a [check constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html):

```
create table sometable (
  -- ...
  ratingSore int not null check (ratingSore between 0 and 10)
  -- ...
)
```

See: [example on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f8ff1cd2a9f38b23fe0695e5c7d3de18)

Important: MySQL versions before 8.0.16 supported check constraints in the syntax, but **ignored** them.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: as said by Mark, recent versions of MySQL (8.0.16+) support a `CHECK` constraint.

---

Regarding the average computation, **the `int` column type only affect the data stored in this column**.

When you will ask to compute the average, you will be able to get decimals as this will only be a "result", not stored in the column.

Comment: There is something: `CHECK` constraints (though MySQL before 8.0.16 ignores them)

Comment: Oh, good to know :) I'll update my answer if you post one then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not correct.  The `int` data type does not take two parameters.  MySQL allows one, which is for *display* purposes only -- the parameter does not affect what actually gets stored.

You seem to want a `numeric`/`decimal` data type:

```
ratingSore numeric(2, 0) not null
```

The "2" says there. are two digits of precision.  The "0" says that none of the digits are after the decimal point.  Together, these say that the column stores any integer value between 0 and 99 -- which seems to be what you are asking for.